# Using Spotipy API to Loop Through a DataFrame - Help Needed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, spotipy

I have a nested for loop that first searches for a songs name based on DataFrame values using the Spotipy API. This for loop is intended to add values from the json output to a list.

Here is the DataFrame I'm calling:
[pandas dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMuov.png)

The for loop pulls each artists name and song, searches for the song in spotipy, and appends those values to a list.
Heres my code:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    search_query = "artist:" + str(row["artist"]) + " track:" + str(row["title"])
    track_id = sp.search(q = search_query, limit= 1, offset = 0, market= 'US', type = 'track')
    print(track_id)
    searchtrack = len(track_id["tracks"]["items"])
    track_name = []
    ids = []
    popularity = []
    for i in range (searchtrack):
        track_name.append(i['name'])
        ids.append(i['id'])
        popularity.append(i['popularity'])
```

Output:

```
json output....
Traceback (most recent call last):
 line 111, in <module>
    track_name.append(i['name'])
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
ile " line 111, in <module>
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `i['name']'
**TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable**
```

My plan is append these lists to the DataFrame above, capture each songs popularity, and drop any unneeded columns afterwards.

However, I can not get the nested for loop to work correctly: `for i in range (searchtrack):`. Ive attempted using i in range, t to enumerate, and other solutions to add each searched value to the list, produce output, and append to the list with no success. I either get back multiple lines of the same song values or an error about non scriptable (like above) or uncallable values.

Any advice on how to get this to work?

Comment: post your actual data please, not an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop, `i` is just an incremental integer value, to access the corresponding track you should use `track_id["tracks"]["items"][i]`, so your loop becomes:

```py
tracks = track_id["tracks"]["items"]
for i in range (searchtrack):
        track_name.append(tracks[i]['name'])
        ids.append(tracks[i]['id'])
        popularity.append(tracks[i]['popularity'])
```